# Can anyone reduce time complexity of this code

Tags: python, sum, max, binary-search, linear-search

You are given three integers A, B, and C. You are allowed to perform the following operation any number of times (possibly zero).
• Choose any integer X such that X ≤ max (A,B, C), and replace A with
A^X, B with B^X, and C with C^X.
Here denote Bitwise XOR operation.
Find the maximum possible value of A+B+C.

```py
A=2
B=2
C=2
def maxSum(a,b,c):
    list=[]
    l=[a,b,c]
    l.sort()
    if a==b==c:
        for x in range(int(a/2),l[-1]):
            new=((a^x)+(b^x)+(c^x))
            list.append(new)
        return list[-1]
    else:
        for x in range(l[1],l[-1]):
            new=((a^x)+(b^x)+(c^x))
            list.append(new)
        return list[-1]
maximum=maxSum(A,B,C)
print(maximum)
```

How to make the code run faster?

I tried using for loop but the runtime was so much. I want to know how to reduce runtime. What are the modifications needed.

Comment: It seems like you can make it so at every bit position (up to the highest bit set in any of the numbers) either 2 or 3 or the numbers have that bit set (3 if all three start equal at that bit position). That gives an easy log(n) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def max_sum(a, b, c):
    for j in range(int.bit_length(max(a, b, c))):
        x = 2**j if sum((n & 2**j) >> j for n in (a, b, c)) < 2 else 0
        a = a ^ x
        b = b ^ x
        c = c ^ x
    return a + b + c
```

So here you perform a number of operations equal to the number of bits of the largest number. `x` is either a power of 2 or 0.

Example:

```
>>> max_sum(8, 3, 5)
30
```